# How do I download multiple large files and saving locally -- URLStream or URLLoader?

Tags: actionscript, air

This is absolutely driving me crazy.  While I'm a fan of the availability of asynchronous calls in AIR, I'm finding that being forced to use them for something that should be SUPER simple is a severe limitation.  So severe that I may end up abandoning AIR and writing native Android and iOS apps instead of using the shared AIR platform.

OK, now that I have that off my chest, here's what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have an app that, when deployed, is relatively small.  But once deployed to a user's device that user will log in using a login name/password.  Once they log in, content specific to that user needs to be downloaded and saved to the local device.  Since the content varies by user I can't include it in the package for deployment.

But I cannot figure out how to accomplish this: say I want to download 10 files and each file is 2-3mb and I want to show a "Downloading, please wait..." view during the download. The application cannot proceed until all 10 files are downloaded.  But since from what I've seen URLStream and URLLoader are both async I cannot figure out how to block the app from opening the "View available content" and say on the "Downloading, please wait..." view.  Can anyone point me in the right direction??

I am new to AIR/Actionscript, but am a seasoned developer.  Perhaps too seasoned in my old ways to think of an elegant solution to the above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at [BulkLoader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/) with a combination of dispatching/listening for completion.  That way you can update the progress meter if you want, so on.  Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks like a great resource. I ended up rolling my own in between the time I wrote my question and you responded but this would have saved a heap of time. Not sure if this library is optimized for mobile use, but I might give it a try anyway.  THANKS!